# Invalid Redeclaration of function in Swift

Tags: function, swift, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write some helper functions and am getting an 'Invalid Redeclaration' error of some similar methods. If anyone can explain why these methods collide I would be very thankful.

```
func CGRectModify(rect: CGRect, x: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)
}

func CGRectModify(rect: CGRect, y: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)
}

func CGRectModify(rect: CGRect, width: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, width, rect.size.height)
}

func CGRectModify(rect: CGRect, height: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, height)
}
```

I would think that because the second parameter has a different external name, the method would be understood to have a different signature. It seems that is not the case.

I've been using Apple's doc for reference, but in the section of [Local and External Parameter Names for Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) I could not find my answer. Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule of "automatic external parameter names" for functions are different from methods.

Swift applies different rules depends on the type of callables.

1. **Functions/Closures** → [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_254)

   No "automatic external parameter names" are performed.

   ```
   func f(x:Int, y:Int) { /* ... */ }
   let c =  { (x:Int, y:Int) -> Void in /* ... */ }

   f(1, 2)
   c(1, 2)
   ```
2. **Initializers** → [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_314)

   "automatic external parameter names" are the default for every parameters.

   ```
   class Foo {
       init(x:Int, y:Int) { /* ... */ }
   }

   let foo = Foo(x: 1, y: 2)
   ```
3. **Methods** → [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_358)

   "automatic external parameter names"  **except** for the first parameter.

   ```
   extension Foo {
       func bar(x:Int, y:Int) { /* ... */ }
   }

   foo.bar(1, y:2)
   ```
4. **Subscript** → document missing?

   No "automatic external parameter names" are performed.

   ```
   extension Foo {
       subscript(x:Int, y:Int) -> Void {
           get { /* ... */ }
       }
   }

   foo[1, 2]
   ```

And a special rule for ...

- **Default Values**

  ```
  func fz(x:Int, y:Int, z:Int = 1) { /* ... */ }

  fz(1, 1, z: 1)
  ```

Of course you can override these default behaviors using:

- `_ name:Type`: disable "automatic external parameter names"
- `#name:Type`: force "automatic external parameter names"
- `externalName internalName:Type`: explicit external name

Answer (score 0):

This actually looks like a bug in the documentation. In the section I originally linked to, [Local and External Parameter Names for Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) the follow explanation is written.

> This default behavior effectively treats the method as if you had written a hash symbol (#) before the numberOfTimes parameter:
>
> ```
> func incrementBy(amount: Int, #numberOfTimes: Int) { 
>       count += amount * numberOfTimes
> }
> ```

This is not the case. When I do add the hash symbol (#) to my second parameter, the compiler error does not occur.

```
func CGRectModify(rect: CGRect, #height: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, height)
}
```

Comment: The document you referred is for methods, not for functions. For functions, see this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_255

Comment: Hey very cool. This makes sense now. Thanks a bunch. (You should make that an answer)